# assert_eq! with floating point numbers and delta

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Is there a preferred way to do an assert with two floating point numbers and a delta in Rust?

For example...

```
let a = 3.0;
let b = 2.9999999999;
assert_eq!(a, b, 0.0001); // Imaginary syntax where a ~= b, within 0.0001
```

Comment: Beware [using epsilons (absolute error margins) for floating point comparisons](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. At the moment, you have to check the difference by yourself or use the [float-cmp crate](https://crates.io/crates/float-cmp).

Also check out the [`f32` constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#associatedconstant.EPSILON).

Answer (score 19):

There's also the [approx](https://docs.rs/approx/0.3.2/approx/) crate which lets you do things like these:

```rust
relative_eq!(1.0, 1.0, epsilon = f64::EPSILON);
relative_eq!(1.0, 1.0, max_relative = 1.0);
relative_eq!(1.0, 1.0, epsilon = f64::EPSILON, max_relative = 1.0);
```

Answer (score 11):

There's no inbuilt [macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/macros.html) for it, but you can create your own.

The following is an implementation of the "absolute error" version described in [this article](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/).

```rust
macro_rules! assert_delta {
    ($x:expr, $y:expr, $d:expr) => {
        if !($x - $y < $d || $y - $x < $d) { panic!(); }
    },
}
```

Specifically, the macro `assert_delta` panics if both the difference between `x` and `y` and `y` and `x` are greater or equal to `d` (the "delta" or "epsilon" value, i.e. the tolerance).

> This is a bad way to do it because a fixed epsilon, chosen because it "looks small", could actually be way too large when the numbers being compared are very small as well. The comparison would return "true" for numbers that are quite different. And when the numbers are very large, the epsilon could end up being smaller than the smallest rounding error, so that the comparison always returns "false".

Given that the previous implementation breaks in various situations, in general, you should **not** use it. You may want to implement a more robust macro, e.g. the one that checks for a "relative error".

Comment: I don't think this works. Consider `x=2.0, y=1.0, e=0.0001`. We expect a panic. `x - y` is about 1, which is not less than epsilon, so the first part of the `or` is false and we test the second part. Part 2 of the `or` is `y - x` which is about -1, definitely less than epsilon, so the condition returns true. Then, we negate the condition and wind up with the branch being false, not taken, and no panic happens even though the two numbers' absolute difference is greater than 1. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is definitely wrong implementation. There should be && instead of ||.

Answer (score 6):

There is another complete crate [assert_approx_eq](https://crates.io/crates/assert_approx_eq) solving this pain, better than float-cmp.

```
use assert_approx_eq::assert_approx_eq;

let a = 3f64;
let b = 4f64;

assert_approx_eq!(a, b); // panics
assert_approx_eq!(a, b, 2f64); //does not panic
assert_approx_eq!(a, b, 1e-3f64); // panics
```